# MPI_send and MPI_recv multiple times

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to implement a simple version of MPI_reduce with point to point routines(MPI_send and MPI_recv). I just want to simulate reducing an array`[0,1,2]` to the root with SUM operation. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>


void my_reduce(void* send_data,void* recv_data,int count, MPI_Datatype datatype,MPI_Op op,int root,MPI_Comm communicator){
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(communicator, &world_rank);
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(communicator, &world_size);

  int tmp=*((int*)recv_data);
    printf("current recv_data is %d\n",*(int*)recv_data);
  if(world_rank==root){
    MPI_Recv(recv_data,count,datatype,root,0,communicator,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    tmp+=*((int*)recv_data);
    *((int*)recv_data)=tmp;
    printf("the value after reduce is now is %d\n",*((int*)recv_data));
  }else{
      MPI_Send(send_data,count,datatype,root,0,communicator);
      printf("now sending %d to root\n",*((int*)send_data));
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    int data[3]={0,1,2};
    int dest;
    dest=0;

    if(world_rank==1){

        my_reduce(&data[1],&dest,1,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    if(world_rank==0){

        my_reduce(&data[0],&dest,1,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    } 

    if(world_rank==2){

        my_reduce(&data[2],&dest,1,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);       
    }
    if(world_rank==0){

        my_reduce(&data[0],&dest,1,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }   
  MPI_Finalize();
  printf("value of destination after reduce is %d\n",(dest));
  return 0;
}
```

I am confused about how to receive multiple tims from send. In this example, it is for root to receive 2 times from the second and third process. My code give the wrong output:

```
current recv_data is 0
now sending 1 to root
current recv_data is 0
current recv_data is 0
now sending 2 to root
```

If I add the two MPI_recv in one branch, that is:

```
    if(world_rank==0){
        my_reduce(&data[0],&dest,1,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        my_reduce(&data[0],&dest,1,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
```

It is still wrong.Could you please give some advice on how to correct this?

Comment: A collective operation has to be invoked by all the ranks of the communicator. In the case of `MPI_Reduce()`, an other requirement is all the ranks use the same value for the `root` argument.

Comment: When you say your program gives the wrong output, please specify what you expect the correct one to be. Note that printing out the current value of `recv_data` happens outside the `if(world_rank==root){ ...}` block, hence you get it three times. Also, there is a problem in rank 0 - it expects messages from `root`, which is also `0`, but it never sends messages to itself, so those `MPI_Recv` calls likely wait forever.